# Customize uikeyboardtype with @gmail.com and numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uikeyboardtype

I want to create a UIKeyboard type that will look like the following.

[image]

This app is only for iPad and none of the default keyboard type seem to match.

Any suggestions for adding buttons to the keyboard type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but what that looks like is the standard keyboard with a custom toolbar on top. It was most likely done using the inputAccessoryView property for the textfield:

```
[textField setInputAccessoryView:inputAccView];
```

[Here is where I took the example from](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html).

Comment: @mattyd, did that answer your question?

Comment: yeah, I think it will, I'll try it later.. I was time blocked from accepting

Comment: @mattyd Oh, OK cool. you will probably have to play around with the looks so it matches the look and feel of the standard keyboard, but I am 99% sure that's what they did in your example.

Comment: You see this in a couple of different apps, for example Wolfram Alpha.  None of them seem to match the accessory view with the system keyboard exactly perfectly, but if you can get it looking generally close enough, no one will notice.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this is not supported in a super easy way by default iOS system keyboards.
However, you can specify your own `UIView` as an "input accessory view" for a text field.
Specifically, look at this method in the UITextField documentation:
[inputAccessoryView.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView)

So you should just be able to create a `UIView`, style it to look very similar to the usual system keyboard UI, add `UIButtons`, and set it as the "input accessory view"
But you will have to do your own work to make the background of the accessory view and the buttons on it fit well with the system keyboard.